# Proper way to pass an array through post?

Tags: php, arrays, post, serialization

I have two pages:

- Graph.php
- List.php

The Graph page does exactly what it is named, graphs data. If there is no post/get data it displays all the data in a given table.

The List page is a huge table which loads around 500-600 rows of data. In the table you can sort and filter the rows using JavaScript. The table is around 14 columns wide.

After sorting the rows in the List page you can press a button 'Graph' that will take the visible rows and graph them on the graph page.

What I am having trouble with is passing these ID's over to the graph page. I started with:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    echo "FOUND SERIALIZED ARRAY<br>";
    $afterSerializeArray = unserialize($_POST['data']);
    print_r($afterSerializeArray);
}
    $beforeSerializeArray = array();
    $beforeSerializeArray[] = 1;
    $beforeSerializeArray[] = 2;
    $beforeSerializeArray[] = 3;
    $serializeArray = serialize($beforeSerializeArray);
?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $serializeArray; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Serialize"/>
</form>
```

I have written the small snippet to grab the ID's of the visible rows and load them into an array, serialize it and pump it into a variable to post it over to the graph.

Should I be using GET? Should I be doing this a different way?

The reason I wanted the filter and sort on a different page than the graph is because users have a lot of columns and options to filter and sort by.

Comment: Don't use GET. it's generally limited to a max length by most browers, and if your serialized data gets silently truncated by the browser (and/or webserver), you'll just get nothing. Use POSt. it's (essentially) unlimited in length.

Comment: i would not post all the data from page one to two, i would post some way to identify the data and reselect it on page 2 for display.

Comment: Like @MarcB said, do not use GET. You could make ajax graph, that refreshes on any of your action.

Comment: @glavić Ajax graph or not you still need to pass it data - so it is safe to use post with a long serialized array?

Comment: It is safe, why not? I would do it like @Dagon told you.

Comment: I dont really understand what @Dagon means.

Comment: Instead of passing all the "filtered" data itself from page 1 to page 2, just pass the filtering criteria from page 1 to page 2: i.e. what filters did the user set up to restrict what data was visible? Then you just reapply those filters (resulting in the same data set), and you use the result for your graph.

Comment: @JonahBishop Honestly, that sounds like a pretty good solution but I am not smart enough to manipulate my jQuery filter script to post what filters were done.

Comment: Where and how do you get data that you serialize?

Comment: @glavić When I click the 'Graph' button it calls a method to grab all the rows that are visible. It pulls the 'title' attribute out which stores the id of the object.

Answer (score 4):

Rather than trying to send array over post you should concatenate these ids with any special character (say ','). This way you will get all IDs as comma separated values in $_POST['data']. Now you can use PHP explode function to get all the values in an array and use them as you wish.

This code sample might help you

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    echo "FOUND Ids<br>";
    $IdArray = explode(',',$_POST['data']);
    print_r($IdArray );
}
    $idarray = array('1','2','3');
    $ids = implode(',',$idarray);
    ?>
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?php echo $ids;?>"/>
<input type="submit" value="Serialize"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Could you expand your answer a little, please? Why is it better to send data as a string rather than as an array? Is it just that it makes accessing it easier?